# Using battery charge port as normal power

Tags: power-supply, battery-charging, charging

So I'm designing a battery charger circuit. It has two connectors in, a main power source and then a powerbank can be connected through a USB C port. I understand that there are various IC's to handle this.

However, since my main power source is not a USB C port, I want to be able to use the USB C port to also power the circuit sometimes, using a standard USB C power source that you can plug into the wall. This is handy when testing the system in a controlled environment. But I'm unsure how to handle this, wont the charging IC sometimes try to "charge" the power outlet? Or is this automatically handled.

Thanks

Comment: What is the 'main power source'? _"wont the charging IC sometimes try to "charge" the power outlet?"_ - which charging IC?

Comment: The main power source is just a standard DC socket capeable of handling 5-36V inputs. A typical charging IC would be this:
https://www.ti.com/product/BQ24721C

Comment: That IC has an AC adapter operating range of 8V–28 V, and is designed to work with 3S or 4S Lithium batteries. It will not work with a 5V supply. Your powerbank puts out 5V, right? What battery will this circuit be charging?